# How does a web Accessibility Screenreader like ChromeVOX read paragraphs?

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

I am testing a site for accessibility using ChromeVOX and I notice that the `<p>` tag content does not get read.  When I tab through the main content, ChromeVOX simply skips over the `<p>` and reads the `<h#>` tags, and links.

I have watched the video: https://youtu.be/OUDV1gqs9GA?t=2748 and at this section, the narrator skips to the first `<h1>` and then mentions a hotkey that will just let the screenreader continue to read all the text.  However, narrator does not mention what that hotkey is.

I have looked at the ChromeVOX keyboard shortcuts, but I cannot find that one:

http://apps4android.org/chromevox/chromevox_keyboard_shortcuts_ref.htm

Also, here is a link to a site to see how screen-readers work:

https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/accessibility/html/good-semantics.html

When I navigate that site with ChromeVOX, it also does not read anything except for the `<h1>` tag.

So, what is the keyboard shortcut or method to read the content in the `<p>` tags or `role="main"` tag? Is there an aria tag that would include those paragraphs?  As far as I can see, this behaviour is common across all sites.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Search</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd> selects the next item on a Chrome Book, on everything else it is

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd>

To just start reading from the current cursor position it is

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>

[You may find this page more useful for shortcuts on ChromeVOX](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/7031755?hl=en-GB), wherever it says <kbd>Launcher</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Search</kbd> you just use <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> on anything other than a ChromeBook.

p.s. this would have been better on https://superuser.com so I am voting to close the question, but I couldn't get the `<kbd>` shortcut to work in a comment (plus my answer was too long) so I answered! :-P maybe migrate the question there.

Comment: I migrated this post to here: https://superuser.com/questions/1607614/how-does-a-web-accessibility-screenreader-like-chromevox-read-paragraphs

Comment: Apparently I didnt have a superuser account, (I have now!), copied answer there so you can close this question if you like.

Comment: I posted a comment on the Superuser question since those keybindings didn't work on MacOS with Chrome browser and ChromeVOX.  The only keybinding that seems to work is `Crtl` to stop the audio.